# Erro ao dar puts de uma variavel dentro do DEF

Tags: ruby-on-rails, stream

Ola.
Não consigo imprimir variavel que esta dentro de um def.

## Script

class Logparser

def initialize(ip, data, code)

```
log = File.open("/project/log_sec/log/log.txt").each do |file|
  parse = file.split(" ")
  data = parse[0] 
  time = parse[1]
  @ip = parse[2]
  method = parse[3]
  url = parse[4]
  code = parse[5]
  ref = parse[8]
  useragent = parse[9]    
end
```

end

def displayparse()

```
puts "IP #@ip"
```

end

O puts @IP não aparece nada

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Você tem que transforma a String em um Array]

A funcionalidade que transforma o uma String em um Array se chama

```
to_a
```

[Documentação no ApiDock sobre o to_a](http://apidock.com/ruby/Object/to_a)

Answer (score 0):

Utilize "#{@variavel}" sempre que quiser imprimir uma variável de ""

#### Exemplo

```
puts "IP: #{@ip}"
```